# Asset catalog slicing using aspect fit

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, asset-catalog

I'm using slicing in the asset catalog to make my image stretch vertically, which seems to work fine if I have the view mode set to `Scale to Fill`

[image]
[image]

But when I change the mode to `Aspect Fit`, it only shows the caps of the slicing like this

[image]

I want to use `Aspect Fit` to keep the round shape of the circular top. How would I make this work with slicing?

For reference, this is my slicing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to slice the image into three pieces:

- A top which has a fixed height in order to keep the proportions of the shape.
- A body which stretches in height according to the content.
- A bottom which also has a fixed height, again in order to keep the proportions.

By slicing like this, you have full flexibility of the height of your content. You would then align these three pieces e.g. by using auto layout.

Comment: That's a good approach. To be clear, you are you talking about having three separate images that make up the one image, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. That way, you're able to respect the shape's proportions of your top and bottom images, while having a flexible/stretchable "body" that follows your content.